# Implementing zoom on a fractal

Tags: c, fractals

I implemented a very basic Serpiensky triangle with the following algorithm:

```
For each pixel (Px, Py)
if (Px & Py)
draw_pixel(Px, Py, color);
```

I was wondering if it's possible to implement a zoom simulation on that, to progressively and indefinitely "go" into the triangle with a nice animation. I can't wrap my head around the formula for that and didn't found anything even closely related on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are using will produce something like this:[image: Serpiensky triangle using bit manipulations]

There can be different ways to obtain a zoom animation effect but the underlying principle is always the same. You display *shifted & scaled* versions of the original frame one-by-one at a fast rate. 
Here, I am describing a very simplistic approach (assuming we reach the same state in `T` seconds using `N` steps):

1. Compute and store the image pixels (for Serpiensky triangle) in a 2D array.
2. Copy the original image into a (separate) frame-buffer.
3. Loop {

   1. Scale down your Co-ordinate space (effectively, zoom into your frame-buffer)
   2. Shift the frame (add small offsets to coordinates, for moving it)
   3. Display the new frame-buffer image at original resolution (Crop pixels that go outside your frame)
   4. Wait for a small time interval (approx. 33ms for 30fps).
   5. if `N`<sup>th</sup> iteration? Goto step **2**
4. } Goto step **3**.

The choice of `N` and `T` depends on how fast and smooth you want the animation to be. The offsets and the scaling factor must be chosen such that: after `N` steps of scaling and shifting, you are left with an image that looks pretty much identical to the starting (original) image.

An important point worth mentioning is that in order for this approach to yield a smooth (i.e. descent looking) animation will require the resolution of your computed Serpiensky triangle to be roughly 20-30 times of the display resolution.

Comment: Initially my idea was to effectively crop a layer of pixels around the image and redraw the fractal from there, but I'm kinda new to graphics and have no idea how to do that. Scale down the coordinate space and crop pixels are what I'm struggling with. Because if I scale down, say, 1 pixel all around the image, when I'll relaunch the algorithm either the same result will appear (since i'm looping through the same pixels coordinates) or either the image will just be cropped 1pixel but will not take the entire screen.

Comment: @Willy I will try to explain it in a completely different way: say we set `Px"` = 1.1 * `Px` before copying into the *frame-buffer*. Only 91% of the original picture will get copied, rest cropped. `Px"` will be a new larger space. After copying is done, we rescale it for displaying at the output resolution. The original image is untouched, all operations we did were on a copy i.e. *frame-buffer*. As a matter of fact, you needn't follow the steps exactly as I have mentioned. Depending on your exact goal, your approach should vary. But I think you have got the overall idea already.

Comment: "After copying is done, we rescale it for displaying at the output resolution."
This is the piece I miss. Do you happen to have some ressources on the matter ?

Comment: @Willy Not sure whether you want information on image manipulations (like scaling, smoothing etc.) or instead looking for information on software/libraries with graphics capability. A very light introduction to the basic image manipulations is at http://www.scantips.com/lights/resize.html. But If you are looking for a graphics library, I would suggest OpenGL. It might seem a bit complicated in the beginning but it is quite well structured and a very powerful graphics library. Read more https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/.